# Multiple Mockito.when not working on same class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

Only the first Mokcito.when is working here, resulting it to return a null, instead of the object.

Ive return two when as, there are two JPA functions being caled inside the service method.

```
@Test
public void testEditComplaintStatusDetail() {

    long id = 1;
    String status = "Investigation Complete";
    EmergencyComplaint editedComplaint = new EmergencyComplaint(id, "No dogs to feed", "Investigation Complete");

    when(emergencyComplaintRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(emergencyComplaint));
    when(emergencyComplaintRepository.save(editedComplaint)).thenReturn(editedComplaint);

    assertEquals(emergencyComplaintService.editComplaintStatusDetails(status, id), editedComplaint);
}
```

Service

```
@Override
public EmergencyComplaint findComplaintDetailsById(long id) {
    return emergencyComplaintDAO.findById(id);
}

@Override
public EmergencyComplaint editComplaintStatusDetails(String status, long id) {
    EmergencyComplaint complaint = findComplaintDetailsById(id);
    complaint.setStatus(status);
    return emergencyComplaintDAO.save(complaint);
}
```

DAO

```
@Override
public EmergencyComplaint findById(long id) {
    return emergencyComplaintRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}


@Override
public EmergencyComplaint save(EmergencyComplaint emergencyComplaint) {
    return emergencyComplaintRepository.save(emergencyComplaint);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Second when-statement can be omitted btw, since mocks always return null by default.

Comment: Please change the parameter order for your asserts. The first parameter is your expected result, the second the actual. Your current order is confusing.

Comment: Please also show how you defined your mock. Your @Before-method might also be helpful.

Comment: I had copied the wrong code, the second mock should return editedComplaint. as far as @Before-method is concerned. I dont have any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update after edit:

Your mock for `save()` won't work if your EmergencyComplaint object does not equals to your editedComplaint object. So you have to change (or at least show) your equals function or widen your expected mocking parameters like this:

```
when(emergencyComplaintRepository.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(editedComplaint);
```

Comment: My bad, it should have returned editedComplaint. Copied the wrong one from the ide. Can you check again now?

Comment: Ah, the object had to be same. OK